# disable "open file" and "save file as" functionality in firefox

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, filemanager

We use firefox in our company and we want to prevent firefox to open a download dialog during saving files.
we want to prevent users change the name of files or rewriting an existing file during download.
for this purpose, chrome has a policy called `AllowFileSelectionDialogs`.but firefox doesn't.
Is there any way or trick to apply the same functionality to firefox?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello. This would be a good question to ask on Firefox Support.  It is not an Ask Ubuntu question. Sorry.

Comment: @David Asking about software running on Ubuntu is on-topic (Firefox is even the default installed browser when you install Ubuntu). Although I would recommend asking Firefox Support as they may give a faster answer, it's fine to ask it here as well.

Comment: The OP is not asking about using Firefox on Ubuntu he is asking a question about an in dept setting beyond what support here can answer, Hence my comment.

Comment: I have already encountered this problem and a GPO on the Active Directory had worked, but from memory it was only the case with Internet Explorer at the time, and we had forced its use on all the PCs (80) of the network. Hard for the users but really effective.

Comment: You mention internet explorer. Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi That's not the same person as OP who commented that

Comment: @Dan Oops......

Comment: It hasn't been worked on yet.... https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1708289

Comment: @WU-TANG yes. I saw it. but is there any library in firefox to be deleted and disable save file as functionality?

Comment: Can I clarify the requirement: people should still be allowed to save files, but they cannot have the dialog and they cannot overwrite existing files. Is this correct? Or is downloading completely forbidden? 

Answer (score 0):

Use the snap version of firefox and remove the apt version. Snaps already are prohibited from accessing pretty much everywhere on the machine except /home/user... Remove that privilege too.

This example uses Opera Browser installed from snap. (wasn't going to uninstall my apt firefox... but you'll get the gist)
[image]

Disabling access to the home directory renders the fileChooser pretty much useless (if there are no other permissions explicitly allowed).

(I would save off the bookmarks/profiles/etc before removing it. I'm not sure if it is the same with the snap version, but whenever I needed to copy everyone's profile/bookmarks/certs/etc. I would just copy the .mozilla directory from the home directory to the new account's home directory.)

Comment: it's not a proper way because this approach prevents users to download the file.
Do you know any other way?@WU-TANG